# URL variable from form to next page

Tags: forms, variables, url, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion. My goal is to share data among URL.
For example, page-1 shares data (e.g. google.com/variable=123) with page-2.
From page-2 I need send this data to page-3 where it is processed as integer (passing it to SQL query).

In page 2 I have form which can submit this data to page 3 but it fails - I get either nothing or the name of variable.

My question: how to temporary store variable from URL on Page 2 and after submit the form send this variable(value) to Page 3?

Part of code which can show my problem:

```
Page1
<a href="Page1.cfm?category=#variable#">ClickOnMe</a>

Page2
<form action="\Some\Path\Page2.cfm" method="post">

<input name="dataFromURL" value="#URL.category#" type="hidden"> 
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>

Page3
<cfoutput>
#form.dataFromURL#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The #variable# on page2.cfm must be enclosed in a <cfoutput> or it won't be evaluated. So you end up submitting the literal string '#url.category#', instead of its value.

Comment: I would also be very cautious about injection attempts. Any time you use "pass-into" variables, especially URL and FORM, you run a risk of your page being easily injected, so validate what you are doing with that variable before you use it.

Comment: Uhh, Thats really great. Thank you for help!

Comment: You can also put the variables into the session scope so you don't have to pass them.

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing this to try out your variable passing. You need use encoding functions as you are passing variables along. Also web pages use forward slashes

**Page1**

```
<cfoutput>
 <a href="Page1.cfm?category=#EncodeForURL(variable)#">ClickOnMe</a>
</cfoutput>
```

**Page2**

```
<cfoutput>
<form action="/Some/Path/Page2.cfm" method="post">

  <input name="dataFromURL" value="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(URL.category)#" type="hidden">  
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</cfoutput>
```

**Page3**

```
<cfoutput>
 #EncodeForHTML(form.dataFromURL)#
</cfoutput>
```

OR

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

Comment: I would also add `<cfparam name="url.category" type="numeric" default="0">` at the top of `page2.cfm` to handle data type validation and give it a default value in case the page is requested without a query string parameter.